# How to develop admin/staff app for food ordering app?

Tags: java, android, mysql, web-applications, google-developers-console

So, I am very new to android development and my goal is to build a canteen ordering app for my school such that students can order food through phone without standing in queue. So, if I build an app for user side how could staff in canteen receive the orders placed through app by students. Should i make another admin app and connect them through database or build an app using Java and connect them using database. Sorry, if this sounds silly. Can you suggest me some possible solutions so that it would be more practical.
P.s. it is my final year project so i want it to look as good as possible.

Comment: I’m afraid it’s too broad for Stack Overflow. You may have better luck with your search engine.

Comment: This sounds like a class project, because I've seen several questions like this in the past couple of days. However, if this is supposed to mimic a real ordering app, then there are three main components: the ordering client on the phone side, the server, and the authentication stuff, which is on the server side. All the client does is to authenticate itself to the server and send/receive information from the user to the server. The client should never talk to the database itself, but only through the server. You will need to learn about security and authentication.

Answer (score 1):

A possible solution for your problem is:

### Firebase

> Firebase is a platform developed by Google for creating mobile and web applications.

It'd provide the admin interface you need to control the staff and the students and its free. At least it wouldn't cost you a dime throughout the project.

It is also very interoperable with the Android Framework. You can start by reading the Documentation [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/)

Answer (score 0):

You can make two apps. One is for the user side and the other one is for the admin side. This is something similar to making an e-commerce app. You can check this playlist to get a better idea about making an admin side and client-side app:

https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLxefhmF0pcPlqmH_VfWneUjfuqhreUz-O

Note: You can use firebase as a database for the quick development of your app.
Firebase documentation:

https://firebase.google.com/docs/android/setup

Answer (score 0):

You can make a Canteen login within your app. It will open with a username password which only Canteen people know. In the Login page just add " Canteen Service?" which takes you to Canteen login.

So no need for a different app for small use. Make all in one, use Firebase for quick setup. Also Firebase Realtime Database's free tier allows 100 simultaneous connections, I think not more than 100 people would be ordering at same moment?